# Tabulate the number of matches between two groups (including zero matches)

Tags: r, dplyr

Say that we have two sets of letters and I want to tabulate their co-occurrence.
For instance, consider the small dataframe `df` with columns `Set1` and `Set2`

library(dplyr)

```
Set1 = c("B", "A", "E", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "E")
Set2 = c("E", "A", "B", "B", "E", "B", "C", "D", "C" ,"D")
df <- data.frame(Set1, Set2)
```

It looks like this:

```
   Set1 Set2
1     B    E
2     A    A
3     E    B
4     B    B
5     C    E
6     B    B
7     A    C
8     B    D
9     A    C
10    E    D
```

The number of matches in each group can be easily calculated with the table function:

```
as.data.frame(with(df, table(Set1, Set2)))

  Set1 Set2 Freq
1     A    A    1
2     B    A    0
3     C    A    0
4     E    A    0
5     A    B    0
6     B    B    2
7     C    B    0
8     E    B    1
9     A    C    2
10    B    C    0
11    C    C    0
12    E    C    0
13    A    D    0
14    B    D    1
15    C    D    0
16    E    D    1
17    A    E    0
18    B    E    1
19    C    E    1
20    E    E    0
```

**This above result is exactly the result** that I am looking for in `Set1` and `Set2`, we have "A" pairing with "C" twice, etc... 
I am also interested in the letters that do not pair such that in `Set1` and `Set2` we have "A" not pairing with "E" and so forth.

With the dplyr package which I like to use for advanced subletting I find that I cannot use the `table()` function on the subsetted dataframe so I heard that the count function was the alternative:

```
df %>%
    count(Set1, Set2) %>% 
    print()

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Set1  Set2      n
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 A     A         1
2 A     C         2
3 B     B         2
4 B     D         1
5 B     E         1
6 C     E         1
7 E     B         1
8 E     D         1
```

This is similar to the result that the table function gave me except that the 0 frequency co-occurences have been discarded. The documentation for the `count()` function states that it does not count missing values so it is behaving exactly as expected.

So how can I obtain the desired result with the dplyr package and all the wonderful dplyr `%>%` piping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to `spread` and then `gather`.  By converting to 'wide' format and specifying the `fill = 0`, it becomes almost similar to the output of `table`, then, `gather` it back to 'long' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   count(Set1, Set2) %>%
   spread(Set2, n, fill = 0) %>% 
   gather(Set2, n, A:E)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
#   Set1  Set2      n
#   <fct> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A     A         1
# 2 B     A         0
# 3 C     A         0
# 4 E     A         0
# 5 A     B         0
# 6 B     B         2
# 7 C     B         0
# 8 E     B         1
# 9 A     C         2
#10 B     C         0
#11 C     C         0
#12 E     C         0
#13 A     D         0
#14 B     D         1
#15 C     D         0
#16 E     D         1
#17 A     E         0
#18 B     E         1
#19 C     E         1
#20 E     E         0
```

Comment: I just learned something new. Thank you for your simple suggestion.